# Android - Currently running activity

Tags: java, android, service, adt

I want to make an Android service that will run in the background and be able to get the name of the currently running activity. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529806/find-running-activities-from-a-broadcast-receiver-in-android ,  duplicated

Comment: That code doesn't do what I want it to do, that code retrieves a list of all currently running activities. I am looking for the one that the user is currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6881991/198996

> Try using getRunningAppProcesses() to get a list of RunningAppProcessInfo. Then go through each RunningAppProcessInfo and check if it is in the foreground